# Wake-on-LAN ethtool arguments

Tags: linux, networking, wake-on-lan

In the ethtool manpage, it mentions wol and the arguments it takes.

> wol p|u|m|b|a|g|s|d...
> Sets Wake-on-LAN options. Not all devices support this. The argument to this option is >a string of characters specifying which options to enable.
>
> sopass xx:yy:zz:aa:bb:cc
>
> Sets the SecureOnâ„¢ password. The argument to this option must be 6 bytes in Ethernet >MAC hex format (xx:yy:zz:aa:bb:cc).

It doesn't explain what each of them (p|u|m|b|a|g|s|d) does. Anyone know where I can find this information?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Formal note: asking for knowledge is fine; asking "how can I find this information?" is fine. But "where can I find this information?" is asking for learning material recommendation, this is off-topic. In my community wiki answer below I included the information and how I found it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manual seems limited. In my Debian the manual does explain. The explanation agrees with [this link](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ethtool.8.html). I got the link from Google and the query was `man ethtool`. This is the explanation:

> `p` Wake on PHY activity
> `u` Wake on unicast messages
> `m` Wake on multicast messages
> `b` Wake on broadcast messages
> `a` Wake on ARP
> `g` Wake on MagicPacket™
> `s` Enable SecureOn™ password for MagicPacket™
> `f` Wake on filter(s)
> `d` Disable (wake on nothing). This option clears all previous options.

Comment: I came here from Google to find out what "PHY activity" means.